# Regex Ignore Match in the middle

Tags: python, regex

I have string that I want to parse.
The digit (0-99) are appended at the end of the string with '_' delimiter.
The same pattern can also be in the middle of the string with the same delimiter.

For example,

```
#1 ..._ADDXNT_5_6_7_8_9_10_11_12_1
#2 ...X_VSVFT_0_5_ADL_R_
```

This is the regex I have

```
((?<=_)\d{1,2})
```

It works for #1 and parses it out `['5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '1']`
However, it also parses `['0', '5']` which I don't want.

For #2, it shouldn't match.

How can get it to only parse the end appended digits and not in the middle?

```
for i in ['_ADTCNT_5_6_7_8_9_10_11_12_1', 'X_VDDFEFSET_0_5_ALL_C_']:
    match = re.findall(r"(?<=)\d{1,2}", i)
    print(match)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex with a positive lookahead:

```
(?<=_)\d{1,2}(?=(?:_\d{1,2})*$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/S9HWoH/1)

**RegEx Details:**

- `(?<=_): Positive lookbehind to assert that we have a` _` at previous position
- `\d{1,2}`: Match 1 or 2 digits
- `(?=(?:_\d{1,2})*$)`: Positive lookahead to assert that we have 0 or more of `_<digits>` strings ahead till end

Comment: @Imsa: Please comment here if this doesn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

i think this will work :

```
(?<=_)\d{1,2}(?!.*[A-Za-z])
```

and this `(?!.*[A-Za-z])` mean not followed by alphabetic characters

[image]

Comment: It works for the most part, but has an issue when there is 3 digit number. For instance `HH_7_9_H_E_ 400`. The above regex returns `40`; however, it shouldn't return anything.

Comment: i was thinking you went number between 0-99 if you went more you can change `{1,2}` with what ever you went because it mean `{min_digit,max_digit`} or simply change it with + to be like this `(?<=_)\d+(?!.*[A-Za-z])` and thats mean one or more digit, i hope that's help you

Comment: Sorry for not clearing describing. I actually do NOT want any 3 digit number. So, it must have `{1,2}`. How can I ignore if there is _DDD at the end is what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: ooh , then make your regex like this `(?<=_)\d{1,2}(?!.*[A-Za-z])(?:(?=[_\n])|(?=$))` the new expression test for either that number followed by _ or \n (new line) or $ (end of text) else will not take it

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to repeatedly match all underscores followed by 1+ digits till the end of the string, and then split on `_`

```
(?:_\d{1,2})+$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OCJjLP/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/bRKJfX)

```
import re

for i in ['_ADTCNT_5_6_7_8_9_10_11_12_1', 'X_VDDFEFSET_0_5_ALL_C_']:
    result = re.search(r"(?:_\d{1,2})+$", i)
    if result:
        print([x for x in result.group().split("_") if x])
```

Output

```
['5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '1']
```